# Concatenate generator output with list in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.3

In the following code I am trying to extract some data from an xml. I would like to make `test.mygenerator('TEST') + tag` return something as one string. For example, `test.mygenerator('TEST')` will return a URI such as "`{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}`" and I need to iterate over each tag with in `some_list` and concatenate it with each URI generated with test.mygenerator('TEST'). I am looking for either a more efficient strategy or a way to make my current code work. The idea behind the code is to be able to extract text from all tags under a URI namespace. The URI namespace can have more than one tag. Thanks.

```
for element in some_xml_tree.iter('{http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/}record'):    
    for tag in some_list:
        for thing in some_xml_tree.iter(test.mygenerator('TEST') + tag)
            print(thing)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to create a list with the elements of `test.mygenerator('TEST')` in it, followed by the elements of `tag`? Do you want to concatenate `tag` to each element of `test.mygenerator('TEST')`? Do you want to iterate over `test.mygenerator('TEST')` and `tag` in parallel, doing something with pairs of items?

Comment: I would like to concatenate `tag` to each element of `test.mygenerator('TEST')`

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work:

```
''.join([i for i in test.mygenerator('TEST')] + [tag])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure but it sounds like you want a generator comprehension along the lines of:

```
(s+tag for s in some_generator('TEST')
```

This will concatenate `tag` to every string in `some_generator`. I'm not sure I understand what `some_xml_tree.iter` does, but this is my best guess at what you want:

```
for thing in some_xml_tree.iter(s+tag for s in some_generator('TEST')):
    print(thing)
```